# VS Code Python Autocomplete using UNC path

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code on a Win10 laptop to develop python program running on Ubuntu workstation. This program is based on TensorFlow, thus I can't install it on Win10.

Both Win10 laptop and Ubuntu workstation are under the same LAN, so I can use "share to local" feature of Ubuntu to share work directory in Ubuntu work station to Win10 laptop, and can access that file via explorer of Win10 just like it is a normal folder of Win10 laptop.

I need to work on Win10 since I can only remote to the Ubuntu workstation, and using remote access with graphic support like Teamviewer/NoMachine/VNC is slow.

VS Code is awesome, everything is fine, except autocomplete. Using conda install libs let autocomplete for numpy, scipy and other libs works fine, but TensorFlow can't be installed on via conda install.

Python extension for VS Code can set extra paths for autocomplete, like shown in this [page](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Autocomplete-Intellisense).

I've shared pip packages location on Ubuntu, thus I can found tensorflow source folder via Win10 explorer via:

```
\\192.168.1.132\dist-packages\tensorflow
```

And I create a workspace setting for VS Code, it create a file:

```
...\work_dir\.vscode\settings.json
```

After adding path, it looks like below:

```
{
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["\\192.168.1.132/dist-packages"]
}
```

After restart VS Code, in a test file:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.<Tab>
```

After I type **Tab**, it gives me 4 spaces, no autocomplete.

I'm wondering if Python extension of VS Code can support UNC paths.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Try creating a directory symbolic link in an elevated command prompt, e.g. `mklink /D tensorflow \\?\UNC\192.168.1.132\dist-packages\tensorflow`. I create junction mount points and directory symbolic links in `C:\Mount`. If that doesn't work, try mapping it to a DOS drive-letter.

Comment: I also recommend mapping 192.168.1.132 to a memorable name in your `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file. In case the address changes you'll only have to modify the one file.